# Regex to match decimal value

Tags: c#, regex, validation, decimal

I have the following regex to match decimals:

```
@"[\d]{1,4}([.][\d]{1,2})?"
```

but I am able to input multiple decimal dots. How can I prevent this? In general, I can have input strings like "2000" or "2000.22". I have tried to use decimal.TryParse but I can input two decimal dots (e.g. 2000..)

Here is my class with method for validation:

```
 public static class ValidationUtils
 {
    public static bool IsValid(string text)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^\d{1,9}([.]\d{1,2})?$");
        var success = regex.IsMatch(text);

        return success;
    }
 }
```

Here is the call in page's code-begind:

```
private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var box = eventArgs.OriginalSource as TextBox;
    if (box == null) return;
    eventArgs.Handled = !ValidationUtils.IsValid(box.Text + eventArgs.Text);
}
```

And the xaml of TextBox:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Nominal, Mode=TwoWay,
 StringFormat={}{0:0.######}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
 NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
 Converter={StaticResource  decimalValueConverter}}"
 PreviewTextInput="OnPreviewTextInput"/>
```

Am I use a wrong event here?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your regex.

```
@"^\d{1,4}([.]\d{1,2})?$"
```

`^` matches the start of the string

`$` matches the end of the string

if you don't do that, you will get partial matches.

Comment: Doesn't the period need to be escaped as well?

Comment: @Petter Not inside a character class.

Comment: I somehow can't input even a dot.

Comment: @Sega, what is your input string? This regex will accepts strings like "1234.12", but not "123." or "12345.123"

Comment: @stema, I can have numbers like 200 or 200.22 and when I have 200 I can't input a dot.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code, where you use this regex. I think it is not an issue with the regex itself.

Comment: @stema even i cant input the decimal, my numeric value is like 123456789.123456789 there is no limit before and after dot.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your regex will match up to the last two numbers, if they are present and thus consider the string as a match. You need the anchors to tell the regex that the number should end with the last digits.

```
^\d{1,4}([.]\d{1,2})$
```

You don't need to put the square brackets around the `\d`, and you can use `\.` to escape the dot, like this:

```
^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a few things.  First, you'll want to start with ^ and end with $ to make sure you don't have any unwanted beginning or ending characters.  Next, you'll have to escape the . to make it a literal .  As you already have noted, you'll want the ? after the grouping as the .## part is not required but allowed.

This makes your final regex the following:

```
@"^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$";
```